Example of a sequence $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that $x_{nk}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $k \geq 2$
Problem Give an example of a sequence $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that $x_{nk}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $k \geq 2$, whereas $x_n$ does not converge as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
This question is from Garling's book (A Course in Mathematical Analysis, Volume 1, Exercise 3.2.16), and has been asked before on MATHEMATICS. (Give an example of a sequence $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that $x_{nk}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $k \leq 2$)
I found one example and would like to share it with you. If anyone finds other examples, I would appreciate it if you could share them as well.
My answer Let $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be sequence such that $x_{n} =1$ when $n$ is prime number, otherwise, $x_{n} =0$. When $k$ isn't prime, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $nk$ isn't prime, so $x_{nk}=0$, and $x_{nk}$ converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Conversely, if $k$ is prime, then for all $n \ge 2$, $nk$ isn't prime so that $x_{nk}=0$ and $x_{nk}$ converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ does not converges because for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a prime number $k$ such that $k \ge n$, so that the sequence is a series of zeros, followed by a sudden jump to $1$.
